# Logstash 6.7.0 fails to start with an error “Error: Permission denied - Permission denied” on macOS Mojave (10.14.4)

Tags: macos, logstash, homebrew

Recently upgraded Logstash (which was installed via Homebrew) on macOS Mojave (10.14.4) to version 6.7.0 and things are not working as expected. When I try to run it manually via the command line—for local development purposes—I consistently get this error:

```
  Error: Permission denied - Permission denied
  Exception: Errno::EACCES
  Stack: org/jruby/RubyFile.java:1263:in `utime'
uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/fileutils.rb:1133:in `block in touch'
```

What’s maddening is when the same exact Logstash config files are used on the RedHat 7 production server where I have Logstash 6.7.0 installed as system service—via [the official Elastic repos](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html)—everything works as expected.

My input config file looks like this:

```
input {

  file {
    path => "/opt/logstash/coolapp/access_log*"
    exclude => "*.gz"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    close_older => "1 hour"
    stat_interval => "1 second"
    discover_interval => 15
  }

}
```

This stuff is fairly simple as far as a config goes and all my settings match valid/accepted settings according to the official Logstash reference manual. But if I comment out the `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` line, my Logstash setup on macOS works as expected.

What the heck is happening to cause this issue? I mean I can be aware of commenting out `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` when I do local development work, but still… This is really annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out… In a way. The issue is obliquely referred to in the error line:

```
uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/fileutils.rb:1133:in `block in touch'
```

And the only temporary solution I have found is to comment out this line in my config:

```
sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
```

It seems that the production server I have running Logstash is using JRuby version 2.5.x and my local macOS version installed via Homebrew is using jRuby version 2.4.x. And apparently `fileutils.rb` in JRuby 2.4.x handles `touch` in cases for non-existent devices (such as `/dev/null`) differently than JRuby 2.5.x. And thus, Logstash fails on my macOS development setup.

So it seems this was all a Homebrew (or macOS?) issue rather than a Logstash issue.

Comment: I was running ELK locally and sincedb_path => "/dev/null" threw me error as well. Removing it works fine.